# Ajax to check xml file every 5 seconds that clears the original data

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I have some js to display XML data on HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xml/odds.xml",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
          var $match = $(xml).find('match[id="670358"]');
          var $result = $match.find('bet[code="Ftb_Mr3"]');
          var $odds = $result.find("choice");
          var game = $match.attr('name').replace('-','<span class="text-danger">vs</span>');

          $("#title").append(game);
          $odds.each(function () {
            odd = $(this).attr('odd');
            $("#odds").append('<li>' + odd + '</li>');
          });
    }
      });
  });
```

This works great however when I try and get it so it checks the XML file every 5 seconds so it reads:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function get_info() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xml/odds.xml",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
          var $match = $(xml).find('match[id="670358"]');
          var $result = $match.find('bet[code="Ftb_Mr3"]');
          var $odds = $result.find("choice");
          var game = $match.attr('name').replace('-','<span class="text-danger">vs</span>');

          $("#title").append(game);
          $odds.each(function () {
            odd = $(this).attr('odd');
            $("#odds").append('<li>' + odd + '</li>');
          });
    }
      });
    }
    setInterval(function() {
      get_info();
    }, 5000);
  });
```

This though gives a delay to start with and then just repeats the data.

How can I edit this so that it shows the data from the XML instantly and then clears the data everytime it checks so I just have 1 set of data showing.

Any help is appriciated, after that just need to work out how to change the decimals into fractions

Answer (score 0):

Ah the clear was so simple had been clearing the wrong id's I added:

```
$('#title, #odds').html(''); //Clear content
```

So it now looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function get_info() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xml/odds.xml",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
          $('#title, #odds').html(''); //Clear content
          var $match = $(xml).find('match[id="670358"]');
          var $result = $match.find('bet[code="Ftb_Mr3"]');
          var $odds = $result.find("choice");
          var game = $match.attr('name').replace('-','<span class="text-danger">vs</span>');

          $("#title").append(game);
          $odds.each(function () {
            odd = $(this).attr('odd');
            $("#odds").append('<li><a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">' + odd + '</a></li>');
          });

    }
      });
    }
    setInterval(function() {
      get_info();
    }, 5000);
  });
```

Just need to solve the delay when it first loads now :)